# Dynamic Layout in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular templates are great to use and I am wondering if there is a way to use these templates to achieve dynamic layout without having to create many directives. For example:

```
<div id="foo" style="width:100%" />

<div style="width:{{ foo.offsetWidth * 0.5}}px" />
```

Is this possible and if so, what's the easiest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how many directives you'll need, but you can use a controller and `ng-style` to dynamically alter CSS. I used it for an HP bar like so:

```
io.on("updateHP", function(data) {
    $scope.hpBar = {width:((data.hp / data.maxHP)*100)+"%"}
    $scope.currentHP = data.hp;
    $scope.maxHP = data.maxHP;
    $scope.$apply();
});

<div>
    HP: <span id="hp" ng-bind-template="{{currentHP}}"></span>/<span id="maxHP" ng-bind-template="{{maxHP}}"></span>
    <div class="health">
        <span ng-style="hpBar"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive allows you to set CSS style on an HTML
>   element conditionally.

Comment: And I can programmatially get to the width of another element inline?

Comment: Yep..you can check it from the fiddle made by Jason Goemaat...http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/3kVmb/2/

Answer (score 0):

[`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) binds css styles to object properties with the same name.  Your example would be ([***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/3kVmb/2/)):

```
<div ng-style="{width: foo.offsetWidth * 0.5 + 'px'}"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, but you're using the controller to help here. This feels like a view concern only and I'd prefer to do this in markup with embedded code.

Comment: Ah, I see, you want to set it to 1/2 the width of the foo element, I assumed you had just used the name 'foo' twice.  I'll leave my answer because it satisfies what the question appears to be, but no there is not a direct way to do that.  You need to write a directive because something needs to listen for resizing events to alter the size.  That wouldn't be too difficult though.